# Unexpected query string parameters error when page is not in base directory with Cherrypy

Tags: python, python-2.7, url, cherrypy

I am currently building a website using cherrypy and have run into an error when attempting to open a page with a query string in the url `http://localhost:8080/protected/my_page.html?pk=3e4e285c-ed33-403e-a7a1-6b79b5f8356d` included I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cherrypy\_cprequest.py", line 670, in respond
    response.body = self.handler()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cherrypy\lib\encoding.py", line 221, in __call__
    self.body = self.oldhandler(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cherrypy\_cpdispatch.py", line 66, in __call__
    raise sys.exc_info()[1]
HTTPError: (404, 'Unexpected query string parameters: pk')
```

I currently host this page in a /protected/ directory which requires authentication. But, if I move a copy of the page back to my root dir (/wwwroot) and then attempt to load the exact same url (besides the /protected/) `http://localhost:8080/my_page.html?pk=3e4e285c-ed33-403e-a7a1-6b79b5f8356d` my page loads successfully and all the fields are populated with the data I expect that matches my query. That then though leaves that page available for anyone to access rather than require authentication.

The page currently should load and if the query string is in the url it should get the value from this line of python code `pk = context.get("pk", default = "")` and then there is a DB lookup using the cx_Oracle python module and the pk variable to find the matching record to display on the page. I tried commenting out the pk variable assignment from my page to see if it would work but I am greeted with the same error.

Besides just moving the page to my base directory to make it work, does anyone have any idea how to resolve this error?

Comment: For now I have just moved all the pages which require having requests in the url to my base directory for the website. If anyone knows how to keep those pages in my other directory which requires authentication it would be great

Comment: Obviously, you need to mount your application to `/protected` route. But nobody is going to help you unless you describe your setup and provide a reproducible code example.